# How to check whether a string has whitespace at the beginning in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, whitespace

I have a string as bellow

```
var str = "  Hello";
```

I can get the first character of the string as

```
var the_char=str.charAt(0);
alert(the_char)
if(the_char === " "){
    alert("first char of the query is space");
    return;
}
```

But the alert is not poping up.I want to pop up the alert if the first character of the string is a space.How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

There are several types of whitespace.

A regex will let you test for more than one...

```
alert(/^\s/.test(mystring));
```

The `^` character anchors the regular expression to the start of the string.

The `\s` will test for space, tab, carraige return, line feed, and more.

---

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> \s Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed. Equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​\u2028\u2029​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]`.

Comment: Well... [I finally did it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134183/173320) You will probably want to participate in the voting of the feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Since JavaScripts String.trim() gets rid of whitespace well, I leveraged it to create a startsWithSpace() function.

```
var startsWithSpace = function(string) {
  return string.indexOf(string.trim()) != 0;
};
```

A new line is counted as whitespace in this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It does pop up:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/w82Wc)

You probably have an Exception being thrown and not caught somewhere in between alerts like in this code which accesses `x.x` even though `x` is `undefined`:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/w82Wc/1/)

You need to track down and fix that error, rather than the code you posted here which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function haswsatbeginning(str){var re=new RegExp('^[ \\s\u00A0]+','g');return((str+'').replace(re,'')!==str);}
var str = "  Hello";
alert(haswsatbeginning(str)); // alerts true

str = ('{^-^}');
alert(haswsatbeginning(str)); // alerts false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`startsWith`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string.prototype.startswith) to check the first character of the string like so.

```js
var str = "  Hello";
if (str.startsWith(" ")) {
    alert("first char of the query is space");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a semicolon after the first alert.  If you're using Chrome or Firefox, you should always check the console for errors before you ask a question.

Comment: That's not really an error in Javascript since the interpreter is required to put the semi-colon back in.

Comment: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

semicolons are optional, and consistency is optional as well

Answer (score -2):

**You dint return anything inside the if loop .. It gives syntax error so only your not getting popup..**

**remove the return statement**

```
var str = "  Hello";

var the_char=str.charAt(0);
         alert(the_char);
         if(the_char === " "){
              alert("first char of the query is space");
             }
```

Comment: The `return;` statement isn't a SyntaxError.

Comment: that return statment should be in a function then it will work.. As of the code snippet given i meant..